# Отсортировать SQL запрос, имеющий groupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

Итак, есть вот такой запрос:

```sql
SELECT `range`,brand_id,name
FROM BrandVariant
WHERE type = 2
GROUP BY brand_id
ORDER BY brand_id ASC
```

И вот такой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В бренда анхель есть несколько записей:

```
Грубо говоря
анехль1 => range 0,
анхель2 => range 1,
анхель3 => range 3
```

Как провести выборку данных, чтобы были выбраны ИМЕННО записи с самым малым range ?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar переписал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT `range`,brand_id,name, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY range,brand_id,name) AS rn 
          FROM BrandVariant
         WHERE type = 2)f1
 WHERE f1.rn=1  
 ORDER BY f1.brand_id ASC
```

Comment: моя субд выдаёт ошибки, для какой субд вы писали ответ?

Comment: у вас range написан в апострофах, попробйте с ними.